# How do I use an attribute which is in a method in class X(foo) in class Y(foo)? And where am I going wrong here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Currently on ex45 of LP3THW by Zed Shaw. The structure of the excercise is similar to ex43, in fact the Engine and Map classes are almost the same. I've slightly changed it, so to Engine(Map), instead of making them two seperate classes, and changed some small aspects of the code as well to make that work, no issues there I think.

However I'm trying to use data from class X(Room) in class Y(Room), specifcally four variables which stores user input, but it isn't working and no matter what I've tried I can't seem to fix it. See below:

```
class Living(Room):

    def __init__(self):
        self.your_name=input("What's your name? ")
        self.friends_name_1=input("What's your first friends name? ")
        self.friends_name_2=input("What's your second friends name? ")
        self.friends_name_3=input("What's your third friends name? ")

    def roomfunc(self):

        #unrelated code, usage of defined variables your/friends_name but those work fine here.
```

Then later on:

```
class Reception(Room):

    def __init__(self):
        self.living=Living()
    
    def roomfunc(self):
        #strings for story

        while True:

            choicereception=input("Type 'A' to leave, 'B' to play with your friends. ")

            if choicereception=="a" or choicereception=="A":
                #print some unrelated strings here
                print(f"The note reads:\nSleep with one eye open, {self.living.your_name}.")
                exit(0)

            elif choicereception=="b" or choicereception=="B":
                #print some unrelated strings here
                return 'first' #this is the next class to progress story

            else:
                print("Type 'A' or 'B'.")
```

As you can see the idea here is to print the original inputted your_name value into that f-string there.
What happened however, is first that it would throw in an error saying that Living() isn't defined or something like that, somehow it got fixed but now I have another problem.

Additionally I'll just add the descriptions for Map() Room() and Engine(Map) but I mostly copied those from ex43.py, apart from the inheritance ofc.

```
class Map():

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        scenes = {
                'living': Living(),
                'reception': Reception(),
                'first': First(),
                'second': Second(),
                'third': Third(),
                'death':Death()
            }

        return scenes.get(scene_name)

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

class Room():
    def roomfunc(self):
        pass

class Engine(Map):

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        super().__init__(start_scene)

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.opening_scene()
        while True:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.roomfunc()
            current_scene = self.next_scene(next_scene_name)

# with following commands at the bottom of the file:
a_game=Engine('living')
a_game.play()
```

As I mentioned, I just expected the name variable to be slotted in, which it does now, but everytime I enter a new Room, even with classes where there is no __init_ constructor and no self.living=Living() in the constructor, the output in the terminal asks me for me and my friends name 3 times. I have to input names 12 seperate times every time I enter a room. [This is the output in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq0Ox.png).

Class with no __init_ constructor and no mention of those variables where it still happens:

```
class First(Room):

    def roomfunc(self):
#0 related code, 0 mention of other classes in here, but still the specified problem.
```

I have no idea what's going on here. Could some please enlighten me as to where its going wrong?

Comment: Every time you call `Map.next_scene`, it creates a new `Living` instance, which re-prompts the user.  I'd suggest that you should (a) not prompt for input directly in `Living.__init__` (do it explicitly in some UI function and then pass that data into `Living.__init__`) and (b) not create new rooms as a side effect of some other method; you probably want to create a dict of rooms as part of `Map.__init__` and then refer to those rooms later.

Comment: Every call to `next_scene()` causes a new `Living()` to be created which causes the `input()`s to run. (plus creates a `Reception()` which also creates a `Living()`)

Comment: @quamrana thank you for the help. could you perhaps explain how I could prevent this?

Comment: @Samswise, I've just started learning python recently, so I'm a little confused as to what you mean. Do I create the input prompts outside of the function and then pass them (the answers to them) into the class? How do I do that exactly? And as per (b), don't I already have a dict of rooms in Map()?

Comment: @new2python You don't have a dict of rooms as an attribute of `Map`; instead you create a new dict on-demand every time `next_scene` is called (and that has a side effect of re-prompting the user).  @quamrana's answer provides a good example of how you'd make that fix so that `scenes` is an instance attribute that gets set up once, when `Map` is initialized.  It's still not ideal to have UI happening in the `Living` constructor, but as long as you're very careful to only ever construct one `Living` object that on its own is enough to solve the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

One part of the solution is to have the `Map` class create the scenes once in its `__init__()` so that its never repeated.

Also, since class `Reception` currently makes its own `Living`, that should be changed to take a reference to a single instance of `Living`.

```py
class Map():

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene
        living = Living()
        self.scenes = {
                'living': living,
                'reception': Reception(living),
                'first': First(),
                'second': Second(),
                'third': Third(),
                'death':Death()
            }

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return self.scenes.get(scene_name)

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

class Reception(Room):

    def __init__(self, living):
        self.living=living
    ...
```

These changes should prevent the problems that you reported.